# Override final method

Tags: scala, overriding, final

Final methods can not be overridden in a subclass. But with the magic of Scala it seems as this is possible.

Consider the following example:

```
trait Test {
  final def doIt(s: String): String = s
}

object TestObject extends Test {
  def doIt: String => String = s => s.reverse
}
```

The method `doIt` in the object `TestObject` has not the same signature as `doIt` in trait `Test`. Thus `doIt` is overloaded instead of overridden. But a normal call to `doIt` always calls the method in `TestObject`:

```
val x = TestObject.doIt("Hello")                //> x  : String = olleH
```

**Question:**
How can I call the original method `doIt` on the `TestObject`. Is this possible or is this method "sort of overridden"?

Comment: Why Scala treats it as different signature? Is it because first is method and second is function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `TestObject` as `Test` like this:

```
(TestObject: Test).doIt
```

Comment: +1. It's indeed nicer to use the type ascription than to cast.

Answer (score 6):

Another a little bit hackisch way is to call doIt with named parameter like this:

```
val x = TestObject.doIt(s = "Hello")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TestObject.asInstanceOf[Test].doIt("Hello")
```

Comment: Don't you think that `asInstanceOf` is overkill here?